# how would look a sql insert for this database tables?

Tags: sql

i how would look an sql insert for this database tables?

language

```
languageID | language
         1 | german
         2 | english
```

word

```
        id | language | text
         1 | 2        | lucky
         2 | 2        | happy
         3 | 1        | glücklich
```

translation

```
  word1_id | word2_id
         1 | 3
         2 | 3
```

Please help people. i have no idea.
PLEASE help.

Comment: Can you tell us more about the tables, are those ID columns auto incrementing?

Comment: Stack overflow isn't a site to beg for people to do your work for you. If you can't demonstrate a basic understanding of what you're working with, you're in the wrong place. Pick up a SQL beginner's book and start there.

Comment: @Pero you need to reformulate your question. I simply don't understand what you need. You want to create the table and insert values?

Comment: I guess you need to learn little bit of database queries for create table and insert statements. You have not mentioned which database you are using. All database systems have good documentation. Please refer that for creating and inserting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there were no foreign keys/triggers or something like that (please provide more info about that), the inserts would look like this:

```
insert into language (languageID, language) values (1, 'german')
insert into language (languageID, language) values (2, 'english')

insert into word (id, language, text) values (1, 2, 'lucky')
insert into word (id, language, text) values (2, 2, 'happy')
insert into word (id, language, text) values (3, 1, 'glücklich')

insert into translation (word1_id, word2_id) values (1, 3)
insert into translation (word1_id, word2_id) values (2, 3)
```

Comment: sorry that i did not tell the whole background. i have on my html file two input fields. one input field for the german word and the other input field for the english translation. i use the mysql DB phpmyadmin and the id`s are auto increment. so i want to save the added vocables in my db and i dont know how to save these two words. the problem is i need it fast i dont have the time to take a book and to learn sql querries. i will do it but this i need fast thats the problem.

Answer (score 1):

At least, to make you get the idea, I give you one example to add one dataset:

```
INSERT INTO language(languageID, language) VALUES (1, 'german');
```

Note that string values should be given in single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Just do a basic `INSERT INTO table (col1,col2) VALUES (value1,value2)`

Now if you want to make this more complex with multiple translations per word inserted all at once you need to build yourself a stored procedure.

The easiest way id say to do this is to have it take in parameters of Language, Text and Translations.

Translations would be a `VARCHAR(MAX)` datatype and you would have each translation seperated by a character such as |, you then split this parameter at each | into a temporary table.

Insert your first untranslated word, use `scope_identity` to get back the ID that you inserted it at, and then use this to insert the translations one by one.

So you need to look at something like this http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/SQLArrayParameterHandling.aspx

The Scope_Identity method in SQL
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx

And making a sql split function
http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/itai/archive/2009/02/01/t-sql-split-function.aspx